# Why does it give an error when trying to do django logging writing its handlers?

Tags: python, django

## settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'database': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'megabot.log.DatabaseHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['database'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propogate':True
        }
    },
}
```

## log.py

```
import logging
from .models import Log

class DatabaseHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        log = self.format(record)
        level = record.levelname
        message = record.getMessage()
        Log.objects.create(level=level, message=message)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = DatabaseHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

## models.py

```
class Log(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm trying to set up recording errors directly to my application

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 76, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py", line 809, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py", line 571, in configure
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'database'
```

Comment: `megabot.log.DatabaseHandler` Does that class exist and has it been imported?

Comment: How to understand it and how to import it? This is done additionally in settings.py ?

Comment: File "/Users/artemivasenko/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: `AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")` This is a common error.  Do a google search, you will find lots of information.